# Codeigniter - The same md5 name on every upload

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have this annoying problem:

Below you will see my messy upload script in which, whenever I upload a video file, I use a md5 function to name it so there are no video files with the same names in my database/folder.

The problem is that when I upload a given file multiple times to the database, it gets stored with the same md5 file name every time. I would really appreciate it if you could help me fix this little bug. I may be tired or something. I tried a hundred different solutions, and nothing fixed it.

Here is my mess:

```
<?php

class Upload_model extends CI_Model {

    var $gallery_path;
    var $videos_path;
    var $thumbnail;
    var $video_name;
    var $upload_data;
    var $file_name;
    var $name;
    var $videos_folder = "http://localhost/upload/videos/";

    //////////////////////////////


    function Upload_model() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->videos_path = realpath(APPPATH . '..\videos');
//        $this->returnFromDatabase();
    }

    function do_upload() {

        $name = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; // get file name from form
        $fileNameParts = explode(".", $name); // explode file name to two part
        $fileExtension = end($fileNameParts); // give extension
        $fileExtension = strtolower($fileExtension); // convert to lower case
        $encripted_pic_name = md5($name) . "." . $fileExtension;  // new file name
        $config['file_name'] = $encripted_pic_name; //set file name


        $config = array(
            'allowed_types' => 'avi|mp4|flw|mov',
            'upload_path' => $this->videos_path,
            'file_name' => $encripted_pic_name
        );

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);



        if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {


            $this->upload_data = $this->upload->data(); //Returns array of containing all of the data related to the file you uploaded.
            $this->file_name = $this->upload_data['file_name'];


            $this->getThumbImage('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\upload\\videos\\' . $encripted_pic_name);


            $insert_data = array(
                'name' => $encripted_pic_name,
                'path' => 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\upload\\videos\\' . $encripted_pic_name,
                'thumb_path' => 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\upload\\videos\\' . $encripted_pic_name . "_t.jpeg",
                'uploaded_by' => 'admin'
            );

            $this->db->insert('videos', $insert_data); //load array to database 

            redirect('/welcome');
        }
    }

    function getVideoInformation($videoPath) {
        $movie = new ffmpeg_movie($videoPath, false);

        $this->videoDuration = $movie->getDuration();
        $this->frameCount = $movie->getFrameCount();
        $this->frameRate = $movie->getFrameRate();
        $this->videoTitle = $movie->getTitle();
        $this->author = $movie->getAuthor();
        $this->copyright = $movie->getCopyright();
        $this->frameHeight = $movie->getFrameHeight();
        $this->frameWidth = $movie->getFrameWidth();
        $this->pixelFormat = $movie->getPixelFormat();
        $this->bitRate = $movie->getVideoBitRate();
        $this->videoCodec = $movie->getVideoCodec();
        $this->audioCodec = $movie->getAudioCodec();
        $this->hasAudio = $movie->hasAudio();
        $this->audSampleRate = $movie->getAudioSampleRate();
        $this->audBitRate = $movie->getAudioBitRate();
    }

    function getAudioInformation($videoPath) {
        $movie = new ffmpeg_movie($videoPath, false);

        $this->audioDuration = $movie->getDuration();
        $this->frameCount = $movie->getFrameCount();
        $this->frameRate = $movie->getFrameRate();
        $this->audioTitle = $movie->getTitle();
        $this->author = $movie->getAuthor();
        $this->copyright = $movie->getCopyright();
        $this->artist = $movie->getArtist();
        $this->track = $movie->getTrackNumber();
        $this->bitRate = $movie->getBitRate();
        $this->audioChannels = $movie->getAudioChannels();
        $this->audioCodec = $movie->getAudioCodec();
        $this->audSampleRate = $movie->getAudioSampleRate();
        $this->audBitRate = $movie->getAudioBitRate();
    }

    function getThumbImage($videoPath) {
        $movie = new ffmpeg_movie($videoPath, false);
        $this->videoDuration = $movie->getDuration();
        $this->frameCount = $movie->getFrameCount();
        $this->frameRate = $movie->getFrameRate();
        $this->videoTitle = $movie->getTitle();
        $this->author = $movie->getAuthor();
        $this->copyright = $movie->getCopyright();
        $this->frameHeight = $movie->getFrameHeight();
        $this->frameWidth = $movie->getFrameWidth();

        $capPos = ceil($this->frameCount / 4);

        if ($this->frameWidth > 120) {
            $cropWidth = ceil(($this->frameWidth - 120) / 2);
        } else {
            $cropWidth = 0;
        }
        if ($this->frameHeight > 90) {
            $cropHeight = ceil(($this->frameHeight - 90) / 2);
        } else {
            $cropHeight = 0;
        }
        if ($cropWidth % 2 != 0) {
            $cropWidth = $cropWidth - 1;
        }
        if ($cropHeight % 2 != 0) {
            $cropHeight = $cropHeight - 1;
        }

        $frameObject = $movie->getFrame($capPos);


        if ($frameObject) {
            $imageName = $this->file_name . "_t.jpeg";
            $tmbPath = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\upload\\videos\\" . $imageName;
            $frameObject->resize(120, 90, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            imagejpeg($frameObject->toGDImage(), $tmbPath);
        } else {
            $imageName = "";
        }


        return $imageName;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is how md5 is supposed to work.

Comment: Try echoing the $name. What does it look like? Is it a null string? or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what matters, CI's upload class has a property called `encrypt_name`. You can set it to true and have your filename encrypted by default without you doing something else. Take a look: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html
Also, since you are using CI, please use the Upload Class, don't write your own when the one provided from CI is so easy to use.

Comment: And all this time this was in front of my eyes... :) Stackoverflow rocks!!!  Thank you , guys!

Answer (score 1):

md5 will always return the same value when used on the same string, so uploading the file with the same name will end up with the same hash, add a random string to the file name

```
$encripted_pic_name = md5(microtime() . $name) . '.' . $fileExtension
```

You also need to be aware that clashes can happen with md5() where two different strings will have the same output. I wouldn't worry about this too much though for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to attach some random characters to the name before you md5 it (though even then it'll still have the chance of a duplicate name).

E.g:

```
$encripted_pic_name = md5($name . $randomStringHere) . "." . $fileExtension;  // new file name
```

md5 will always give the same output for the same input, so if you upload the same file twice, then yes, you have already used that hash.

If you just want random names, then you don't even need to use MD5 and could just dynamically create a random string everytime a file is uploaded (a, b, c, etc to z, then aa, ab, ac, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If the file name is same then it will return the same `md5 hash`
For this you have to `encrypt` `unique name or number`

You can use

```
$encripted_pic_name = md5(strtotime()) . "." . $fileExtension;  // new file name
```

**or**

```
$encripted_pic_name = md5(uniqid()) . "." . $fileExtension;  // new file name
```